# cannot config LDAP in filenet p8 5.2

Tags: active-directory, ldap

i tried to fulfil this form many times and click "test LDAP connection". it's alway return success. but when i click "run task", it's alway return

```
Running the task failed with the following message: The LDAP authentication configuration failed.
WASX7209I: Connected to process "server1" on node p8 using SOAP connector;  The type of process is: UnManagedProcess
test standalone LDAP repository
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\FileNet\ContentEngine\tools\configure\tmp/configureldap.tcl"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.cmdframework.CommandException: SECJ7340E: Exception raised trying to connect to LDAP server: AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db0
```

form: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlfuw.png

sorry i cant post image.

i used window server 2008r2 with a domain controller.

please help me fulfil this form!

Comment: Have you tried actually filling out some credentials in the fields for it? And a base DN?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about file net, but your error message says you provided wrong credential (wrong user or pwd) - "LDAP err 49, data 52e".
Check your password, and make sure you are provide user identity in correct form.